# How to make flutter app responsive, for all kind of screens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I mean are there some principles to follow so that the app works on all screens ?
I know that for example it is a good thing to use as much as we can multiples of `MediaQueries.of(context).size.width` and height to give size to containers, but sometimes we need to give some fix sizes, in pixel.
And in these cases, most of the time, overflows appear. So in order to build responsive apps, are there some rules to follow, or is it case by case and depending on the situation their are some solutions.

Comment: Sounds like you need flex. Have a read of https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-part-4-renderflex-children-have-non-zero-flex-77734ca0b5c Also for text https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Comment: I wrote a simple solution based on a third party package here https://jaycoding.tech/tutorials/guides/how-to-create-a-responsive-app-in-flutte-xmafdg as I don't think MediaQuery is sufficient. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic approaches to creating Flutter apps with responsive design:

Use the [LayoutBuilde](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)r class: From its builder property, you get a BoxConstraints. Examine the constraint's properties to decide what to display. For example, if your maxWidth is greater than your width breakpoint, return a Scaffold object with a row that has a list on the left. If it's narrower, return a Scaffold object with a drawer containing that list. You can also adjust your display based on the device's height, the aspect ratio, or some other property. When the constraints change (e.g. the user rotates the phone, or puts your app into a tile UI in Nougat), the build function will rerun.

Use the `MediaQuery.of()` method in your build functions: This gives you the size, orientation, etc, of your current app. This is more useful if you want to make decisions based on the complete context rather than on just the size of your particular widget. Again, if you use this, then your build function is automatically rerun if the user changes the app's size somehow.

These other widgets may also be useful if you want to dynamically adjust an app's display:

[AspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) lets you force a child widget to a particular aspect ratio.

[FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) scales its child to fit.

[CustomMultiChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) lets you lay out your children based on the incoming size.

Source : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps.

Hope this could help you. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, I understand. But this concerns especially decisions to make. What if you have a container of a fixed height that you have to display, no matter the size of the screen. What should you do ? Make it scrollable ?